# How to create custom kml layers based on collections of towns

Tags: kml, microsoft-power-map-excel

I'm currently working with a dataset that uses these custom regions. Essentially, these regions are clusters of 10-20 towns that border each other. These regions are analogous to counties, although their borders are different. Annoyingly, these regions are only defined by lists of towns: there's no kml file or something similar that defines these regions.

I'm using [Microsoft Power Map for Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-Power-Map-88a28df6-8258-40aa-b5cc-577873fb0f4a) to create a map of these regions. Microsoft Power Map is able to create maps based off of state/county data automatically. But for it to work with customized regions, I need to import a custom kml file that defines these regions.

Since these regions are clusters of towns, is there a way to take a kml file that represents town borders, and somehow merge the towns into these larger regions?

I'm really new to this, so ideally answers won't require in-depth knowledge or expensive software!

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend 3 ways to get a KML file. Also KML was developed to be used with Google Earth, so creating it without the assistance of software would be very difficult, I have no idea how it would be done.

1) Free Easy - google custom maps browser. Using this you can import CSV, KML, XLSX or GPX files directly to a google map and then you can export it to KML to get your file. This is free and easy.[image]

link: https://www.google.com/maps/d/?hl=en_US&app=mp

2) Free - Moderate Research, You could get either Google Earth Pro or Arc Earth. I know Google Earth is now free and Arc Earth I believe is too. You can use this software to import data and again export as KML

It apparently won't let me link the Google Earth Download, because I'm not reputable enough, but it is an easy google search.

3) Arc GIS - Not Free - Would need to train up on it.